# Is this really the proper way to check the count of an optional string in Swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am scrolling through an array of many things in app.  One of the items in the array is a string, and it is an optional. I've edited out everything else since my question is about the strings.

At one point I need to call some functions on the strings, if they exist.

Both of these appear to work

```
if newItem.item?.count ?? 0 > 0 { ...
```

and

```
if let current = newItem.item,
            current.count > 0 {
```

The top one is cleaner, but I can read the second one easier. The first looks like a cousin of a ternary conditional. I simply want to clarify that even if I am doing it correctly, if there is a more accepted way to do it.

Comment: I think it mostly comes down to personal preference. These are also not the only alternatives, e.g., `if !(newItem.item?.isEmpty ?? true)`. You could also consider making an extension for the type of `newItem`, like `var hasContent: Bool { (item?.count ?? 0) > 0 }`, and then `if newItem.hasContent`...

Comment: Wait, what? You have an array of Optional strings? (`[String?]`)?

Comment: @DuncanC No I have an array of many things, I'm merely editing it down to the Strings part for this question

Comment: I still don't understand the situation. What is the type of `newItem`? Where is the array in your question?

Comment: @Arkku Could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct? Or is this one of those situations where I should just delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a default against a number is code stink. Deodorizing usually involves [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/map(_:)-7txtz)

```swift
if newItem.item?.count.map { $0 > 0 } == true {
```

or better usage of properties.

```swift
if newItem.item?.isEmpty == false {
```